# MvxHttpImageView binding not updated

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following code

`<Mvx.MvxHttpImageView xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/TestServices.Droid"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      local:MvxBind="{'ImageUrl':{'Path':'ThumbNail'}}"`

Where I am passing an image url to the ThumbNail property. The above code is part of an ItemTemplate which is being passed an ObservableCollection of TestModel objects as below.

```
public class TestModel
{
   public string ThumbNail
   {
     get; 
     set;
   }
   public string Name
   {
     get; 
     set;
   }   

   ....
}
```

The Name property is also bound in the above Template to a TextView and it shows up properly as do other string values. The only issue is that the Image does not show up.
I have tried setting the Image Url upfront in the constructor of the ViewModel and it works then. But when I add fetched values to the collection in the Completed event of my web service thats when the Image is not displayed. I have verified the path to the image url in the completed event and it is right. What could be going wrong here. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I was using backslashes for creating the url by concatenating strings, changing them to forward slashes turned it into a proper link and its working fine now. Thanks a lot for the help Stuart

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's going wrong....

But some things to consider experimenting with are:

- setting the MvxBindingTrace level to Diagnostic - does the output panel tell you anything interesting?
- if you are updating the url dynamically then do you need to fire the property changed event
- if you add a textview with its `Text` bound to the image url, then does this update correctly?
- does using `wrap_content` for both height and width really make sense here? What happens if you fix height and width to `100dp` instead?
- does the app work if you use known good image URL - eg a URL from http://placekitten.com?
- does the app work if you set a default image to a local file (eg a resource or asset) which is shown while the http image is loading?
- do the sample apps work for you - eg the bestsellers or twitter samples? If so, then can you see what they do differently?
- can you step into the mvx http image source - are the properties and methods being called at all? If they are, then do they look like they are being called correctly or oddly in any way?

Try those suggestions and I suspect you will find a way forwards. Good luck with the debugging.

if these suggestions don't help, please try adding more info, including info on which version of mvvmcross you are using, which version of Android, which phone or emulator, etc.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, the url from PlaceKitten works. Could it be that my url is too long. When I debug the code the ThumbNail property does seem to have the full url link which is valid but on previewing the url string in the quickwatch window I get '...' towards the end. Is there a limit to the length of the Url